# Error when running a dot-sourced script after executing it

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I've got very weird behaviour which I suppose is related to dot-sourcing somehow, but I cannot wrap my head around it. Here's what I have:

A script `sourced.ps1` which contains the two functions and a class:

```
class MyData {
    [string] $Name
}

function withClass() {
    $initialData = @{
        Name1 = "1";
        Name2 = "2";
    }
    $list = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[MyData]
    foreach ($item in $initialData.Keys) {
        $d = [MyData]::new()
        $d.Name = $item
        $list.Add($d)
    }
}

function withString() {
    $initialData = @{
        Name1 = "1";
        Name2 = "2";
    }
    $list = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[string]
    foreach ($item in $initialData.Keys) {
        $list.Add($item)
    }
}
```

I also have a script `caller.ps1` which dot-sources the one above and calls the function:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

. ".\sourced.ps1"
withClass
```

I then call the `caller.ps1` by executing `.\caller.ps1` in the shell (Win terminal with PS Core).

Here's the behaviour I cannot explain: if I call `.\caller.ps1`, then `.\sourced.ps1` and then `caller.ps1` again, I get the error:

```
Line |
  14 |          $list.Add($d)
     |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "1".
```

However, if I change the `caller.ps1` to call `withString` function instead, everything works fine no matter how many times I call `caller.ps1` and `sourced.ps1`.

Furthermore, if I first call `caller.ps1` with `withString`, then change it to `withClass`, there is no error whatsoever.

I suppose using modules would be more correct, but I'm interested in the reason for such weird behaviour in the first place.

Comment: Unrelated to the question but why not, _since you're already creating a class_, create the methods that would replace the outside functions for your class?

Comment: It's a subjective thing, I personally prefer to separate data and behaviour when possible and use pure functions since that's how it's done in the languages I tend to favour.  If I don't need to access to and don't mutate the instance frequently, I don't use methods and instead use functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Written as of PowerShell 7.2.1</sup>

- A given ***script file* that is both dot-sourced *and* directly executed** (in either order, irrespective of how often) **creates *successive versions* of the `class` definitions in it** - these are distinct .NET types, even though their structure is identical. Arguably, **there's no good reason to do this, and the behavior *may* be a bug**.
- **These versions**, which have the same full name (PowerShell `class` definitions created in the top-level scope of scripts have only a *name*, no *namespace*) but are housed in different dynamic (in-memory) assemblies that differ by the last component of their version number, ***shadow* each other, and which one is effect depends on the context**:

  - Other scripts that dot-source such a script consistently see the *new* version.
  - Inside the script itself, irrespective of whether it is itself executed directly or dot-sourced:

    - *In PowerShell code*, the *original* version stays in effect.
    - Inside *binary cmdlets*, notably `New-Object`, the *new* version takes effect.
    - If you *mix* these two ways to access the class inside the script, *type mismatches* can occur, which is what happened in your case - see sample code below.
- While you can technically avoid such errors by *consistently* using `::new()` *or* `New-Object` to reference the class, it is **better to avoid performing both direct execution and dot-sourcing of script files that contain `class` definitions to begin with.**

**Sample code**:

- Save the code to a script file, say, `demo.ps1`
- Execute it *twice*.

  - First, by direct execution: `.\demo.ps1`
  - Then, via [dot-sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-): `. .\demo.ps1`
- The type-mismatch error that you saw will occur during that second execution.

  - Note: The error message, `Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "1"`, is a bit obscure; what it is trying to express that is that the `.Add()` method cannot be called with the argument *of the given type*, because it expects an instance of the *new* version of `[MyData]`, whereas `::new()` created an instance of the *original* version.

```sh
# demo.ps1

# Define a class 
class MyData { }

# Use New-Object to instantiate a generic list based on that class.
# This passes the type name as a *string*, and instantiation of the 
# type happens *inside the cmdlet*.
# On the second execution, this will use the *new* [MyData] version.
Write-Verbose -Verbose 'Constructing list via New-Object'
$list = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[MyData]

# Use ::new() to create an instance of [MyData]
# Even on the second execution this will use the *original* [MyData] version
$myDataInstance = [MyData]::new()

# Try to add the instance to the list.
# On the second execution this will *fail*, because the [MyData] used
# by the list and the one that $myDataInstance is an instance of differ.
$list.Add($myDataInstance)
```

Note that if you used `$myDataInstance = New-Object MyData`, the type mismatch would go away.

Similarly, it would also go away if you stuck with `::new()` and also used it to instantiate the *list*: `$list = [Collections.Generic.List[MyData]]::new()`